# Firebase V3 and Social Login with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework, firebase, facebook-login

I am just trying to create a simple social login (e.g.: google, Facebook,...) inside a Ionic App and using Firebase V3 as backend. Unfortunately all the example and tutorial that I found on the internet seems to be broken and do not work with the new API v3.

For example I tried to follow this tutorial (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/social-login-with-ionic_77.html?showComment=1465144743780#c7688518627861813273)

but apparently I am not able to access the global variable Firebase that was previously available and therefore from this snippet of my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'firebase'])

.constant('FirebaseUrl', 'https://ionicle.firebaseio.com/')

.service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
```

I get the following error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Firebase, http://localhost:8103/js/app.js, Line: 12
```

Comment: did you load the two files, `firebase.js` and `angularfire.min.js`?

Comment: Yes, i dis include them.

Answer (score 1):

```
facebookAuth: function () {
    ngFB.login({ scope: 'email' }).then(
        function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log('Facebook login succeeded', response);

                var credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
                    response.authResponse.accessToken);

                firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // The email of the user's account used.
                    var email = error.email;
                    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
                    var credential = error.credential;
                    // ...
                });

            } else {
                alert('Facebook login failed');
            }
        });
},
```

more details here: http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/firebase-3-0-ionic-facebook-login

Comment: I was able to integrate the code inside my and now when this code run (from my controller) it opens the in-app-browser for the login. 

Unfortunately I always get this message from Facebook: 
"Can't Load URL: the domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains".

I tried to add the a new platform in my app on Facebook, but it does not work, because the URL from where it comes the request is not my local ip.
I am also not able to find the OAuth settings inside the Facebook app.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `ionic serve --address localhost`

Comment: It works from the browser, but not from the app. If I do "ionic run ios" is not working. Any suggestion?